# Select box not working properly after ajax

Tags: jquery, html

I have this select box:

```
<div id="opcionesdiv"><div id="o1">
Filtrar por Ciudad
<select name="ciudad" id="ciudad">  
<option value="MEDELLIN">Medellin</option>  
<option value="MANIZALES">Manizales</option>  
</select>  
<br><input name="select_comprobar" id="select_comprobar" type="button" value="Comprobar"/>
</div></div>
```

I have a function like this:

```
$("#select_comprobar").on('click', function(event) {
    tacuba = $("#ciudad option:selected").val();
    if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
        ca = "2";
    } else {
        ca = "3";
    }
    var page = "1";
    dan = "g";
    deb = tacuba;
    loadData(page, dan, deb);
    return false;
});
```

the previos code works fine  loadData() make some ajax call.

But I have another function like this:

```
$('#container .pagination li.active').live('click', function(e) {
    var page = $(this).attr('p');
    if (ca == "3") {
        dan = "g";
        loadData(page, dan, deb);
    } else {
        loadData(page);
    }
    return false;
});
```

If a make a click on the "select_comprobar" button and call the second function works only once and then Im getting this (the list appears below and I can't use it):

[image]

Comment: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9. Use `.On()` instead.

Comment: plz include the loaddata() definition in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.live` is deprecated and has been replaced with `on` in jquery 1.9.

try replacing

```
$('#container .pagination li.active').live('click', function(e) {
```

with

```
$(document).on('click', '#container .pagination li.active', function(e) {
```

Also, check if `#container .pagination` have `.active` `<li>` after the AJAX request is done.